# Calculate LDAP Memory Usage through java

Tags: java, memory, ldap, jndi, openldap

I have one LDAP server (openLDAP) which would have a lots of attributes and users. From previous data, it is expected that the size of ldif file would go approx 10 GB.

Basically, I want to know that when this server would go live

- which attribute as a total is taking largest size in memory
- whose user's data is largest in memory.

The purpose of having this information is that if I would know that any attribute or user is taking largest size, I can take required action for that particular attribute or user, may be deleting that user etc. so that memory usage of the server can be controlled.

I am planning to use JNDI for this tool. Through JNDI, I can get all attributes and their values, But how I can calculate how much memory these attributes are taking on server ?

Comment: Why? An LDAP server uses a *database.* Attributes aren't kept in memory at all, except when they form part of a lookup or search result, when they are temporarily in memory while being retrieved and sent. If you want to control the maximum size of individual attributes you can use the 'constraints' overlay.

Comment: I agree that LDAP server uses a database for storing the data and disk size is not constraint. Constraint is memory. What I want to calculate that suppose a user is active on LDAP server so it would take some amount of memory on LDAP server. So, how much memory is required if all users become active. Also, if any particular attribute is taking more size in memory, I will impose constraint on that attribute. But, for this I need to know which attribute is taking largest size.

Comment: Users aren't 'active on LDAP server' at all. They form a brief connection to login and find their roles and groups, then that's it, the connection is closed. From that point on, i.e. from the completion of the login phase, the amount LDAP server memory being used by the user is zero. The probability of all users being active at the same time is approximately zero.

Comment: In my case, LDAP server is not storing only login related details, but it also has user specific parameters and there are various such parameters so I think connection would not get closed after login. Instead it would remain active till user session ends. so there is a probability that many users are active on LDAP server

Comment: The user specific parameters should get loaded into the application, and the application should close the connection after login, and form short lived connections to update the parameters where necessary. Same as for any other database.